# How to organize scores that belong to same condition in R

Tags: r

I've been searching for hours for a solution to my problem, but since I'm new to R and programming, I haven't really got the terminology down well enough to effectively search online for help.

Below is a simplified version of the data I am working with. In the full data there are close to 200 different items, and 24 subjects.

I need to be able to work with the data in terms of which "item" the scores belong with.
For example, I would like to be able to perform basic functions such as calculate the means for all the First scores on Item 3, or all the Second scores for Item 2 etc.

How should I approach this?  Thanks!

```
Subject Item    First score     Second score

  1      1         0.92         0.58    
  1      2         1.00         1.00    
  1      3         1.00         0.69    
  2      1         0.90         0.58    
  2      2         0.95         0.90    
  2      3         1.00         0.92
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `split()`

```
FirstScore <- c(0.92,1.00,1.00,0.90,0.95,1.00)
Item <- rep(1:3,2)
FirstScoreByItem <- split(FirstScore, as.factor(Item))
```

To access scores for each item, use

```
FirstScoreByItem[1]
```

To calculate mean, use

```
mean(FirstScoreByItem[1])
```